# kafka reassign-partitions job stuck in pending

Tags: apache-kafka

I lost two out of three kafka nodes in my cluster leaving the third one as the leader for all partitions and sole ISR. The first two nodes are not coming back so I want to reassign the partitions to two different nodes.

I have tried using both the yahoo kafka-manager tool and also the kafka-reassign-partitions.sh tool. Both start the job, but in the yahoo kafka-manager the reassignment job shows a status of "pending" forever.

- What are the possible causes of this?
- Are there additional ways to debug this?
- Is it possible to "manually" move the partitions to new nodes?

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

This could happen when you add brokers with different major version to the cluster, when the API of intra-broker communication has changed between versions, so the controller node can't assign them partitions.
If this is the case, you will need to set a special property in the **newly added** brokers, to degrade its api version so it will be able to communicate with the old brokers.
If this is the case, please refer to the upgrade guide of the newer version (e.g, for 2.4 - https://kafka.apache.org/24/documentation.html#upgrade)